# TypeScript issue - TypeError: Cannot read property 'watchRun' of undefined

Tags: typescript, webpack, jsx, typescript2.0

Im trying to convert the JSX files of my ReactJS app, one by one to TS. Hence I will have both JSX and TS files running at the same time. (Hence added rules for both in webpack as given below):

This is the part of my webpack config that processes jsx and ts files:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ["awesome-typescript-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ["babel-loader"]
        },
        ]
    }
```

But when I run webpack, Im getting the following error:

> Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'watchRun' of
>   undefined

Packages used:

```
"webpack": "^2.2.1"
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.0.0-1", 
"typescript": "^2.7.2",
"@types/react": "^16.0.40",
"@types/react-dom": "^15.5.7",
"babel-core": "^6.23.1",
"babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
```

I looked up online but nowhere I could find resources giving hint on this watchRun issue.

Thanks.

Comment: follow this issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6357

Comment: @KenrySanchez Thanks. The issue was happening due to version mismatch. Closing the thread.

Comment: could you post the solution here? It will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. My problem is I'm using Webpack 3, which doesn't work with awesome-typescript-loader@5. You are using Webpack 2 so I bet it's the same problem.

To solve either upgrade Webpack or downgrade awesome-typescript-loader

Answer (score 9):

The `awesome-typescript-loader` 5.x is compatible with webpack 4.x, your webpack version is too old. Try upgrading your webpack to 4.x or downgrading your `awesome-typescript-loader` version.

Comment: This also happens with webpack@4.8.3, typescipt@2.8.3 and awesome-typescript-loader@5.0.0 for me :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use 4.x edge version of storybook which depends on the correct version of webpack (which is not the case of the current stable 3.x)

Example: @storybook/react@4.0.0-alpha.8 works with awesome-typescript-loader@5.x

Comment: With what version of webpack? Can you post an example config.js and webpack.config.js? I cannot make it work, and can't find any typescipt examples for storybook v4 out there yet :(